# Excel: Find out who password protected a individual sheet on book

Tags: microsoft-excel, passwords

Is there anyway to see **who** password protected a worksheet?

The book is not locked and is veiwable/editable with exception of one sheet that is locked.

We do not know the password and have no clue who locked it in the first place. Hoping that I can find out who password protected the book so we can gain access.

Is there anyway this information is somehow stored in excel via `Environ` or `UserName` etc.

Comment: Is this the "you need a password to open the file" or a "you need a password to edit this workbook" type of protection? (I suspect the former). IIRC, you can't get the author of a protected file from it's properties. Have you tried getting previous versions of the tile to see if there is one that isn't password protected?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Password to edit the workbook - yes I have restored backups and all have passwords on this one sheet and I know I didn't put it there so I need to know who did. I always store passwords on a xlVeryHidden sheet in white text and this book does not have a xlVeryHidden sheet

Comment: So you can open the book in "Read Only" mode?

Comment: Only one sheet is locked. I will edit the question - sorry for confusion

Comment: Ah! if only one sheet is locked, you should be able to remove the password by editing the Sheet's XML from the file structure. As for finding who put it there, that's above my pay grade ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel does not track which user set a password on a worksheet. At best it will store the name of the document authors in the file properties.

Depending on your environment, you may be able to obtain information from outside Excel that would help you narrow down the list of suspects. For example, if your workbook is stored on a Microsoft SharePoint site there is a edit history that includes which users made edits.